# Object.fromEntries doesn't work as expected when restoring array from URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Simple code:

```
const o = { arr: ['a', 'b'] }
const s = new URLSearchParams(o).toString();
// restore:
const r = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(s));
console.log({ r })
```

Outputs:

```
  r: { arr: "a,b" } // expected: r: { arr: ["a", "b"] }
```

How to make Object.fromEntries to return the expected array?

Comment: add this line r.arr = r.arr.split(','); before the last console.log

Answer (score 4):

URLSearchParams coerces values to strings. Here the value `[ 'a', 'b' ]` is an array, so the `toString` method of the array is called, which is like `arr.join(',')`, producing the string `"a,b"`.

```js
new URLSearchParams({ arr: ['a', 'b'] }).get('arr'); // "a,b"
```

This happens when you initialize the USP object — it’s not related to `Object.fromEntries`. Neither API can round trip this serialized value automatically since it doesn’t know you want that comma-delimited string to become an array of strings. You could write custom deserialization logic for the values though.

---

Array-like or set-like values in search params are often represented as multiple occurrences of the same key. To initialize a USP instance like that you’d pass in entries rather than a record-like object. For example:

```js
const usp = new URLSearchParams([ [ 'arr', 'a' ], [ 'arr', 'b' ] ]);

usp.getAll('arr'); // [ 'a', 'b' ]
usp.toString();    // arr=a&arr=b
```

That approach to “plural” values has some advantages (the USP API is well-suited to it and it doesn’t involve any custom DSLs getting laid on top of the real URL syntax & semantics) and disadvantages (interpretation requires specific knowledge — the intended “type” of a param isn’t communicated in the source as you can’t generically distinguish a param representing an array with one member from one which is meant to be a singular value).

If you do handle arrays in this manner, you couldn’t use `Object.fromEntries(usp)` directly to turn it into a generic object, though — it would end up always setting `arr` to the last value that appeared. However you could do some mapping logic in between that takes care of the keys you wish to interpret as arrays.